# How to properly connect a scalar to a vector entry?

Tags: openmdao

We're searching a way to connect scalars (as an output) to vector entries (as an input).

In the ["Nonlinear Circuit Analysis"](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/examples/circuit_analysis_examples.html) example, there is a workaround in the `class Node` which loops over the number of scalars and adds each scalar as a new input. In the `class Circuit`, the added inputs are then accessed by their "*indices*" (e.g. `'I_in:0'`).

In our case, this loop must be integrated by a new Component, which solely loops the new inputs. This is why we'd like to avoid loops and directly use vector and matrix operations. In terms of the Circuit example, a way to achieve this would be to use some kind of target indices (see `tgt_indices`), which are not implemented (yet ).
In this case both classes would look like this:

```
class Node(om.ImplicitComponent):
    """Computes voltage residual across a node based on incoming and outgoing current."""

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('n_in', default=1, types=int, desc='number of connections with + assumed in')
        self.options.declare('n_out', default=1, types=int, desc='number of current connections + assumed out')

    def setup(self):
        self.add_output('V', val=5., units='V')

        self.add_input('I_in', units='A', shape=self.options['n_in'])
        self.add_input('I_out', units='A', shape=self.options['n_out'])

    def apply_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, residuals):
        residuals['V'] = 0.
        residuals['V'] += inputs['I_in'].sum()
        residuals['V'] -= inputs['I_out'].sum()

class Circuit(om.Group):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_subsystem('n1', Node(n_in=1, n_out=2), promotes_inputs=[('I_in')])
        self.add_subsystem('n2', Node())  # leaving defaults

        self.add_subsystem('R1', Resistor(R=100.), promotes_inputs=[('V_out', 'Vg')])
        self.add_subsystem('R2', Resistor(R=10000.))
        self.add_subsystem('D1', Diode(), promotes_inputs=[('V_out', 'Vg')])

        self.connect('n1.V', ['R1.V_in', 'R2.V_in'])
        self.connect('R1.I', 'n1.I_out', tgt_indices=[0])
        self.connect('R2.I', 'n1.I_out', tgt_indices=[1])

        self.connect('n2.V', ['R2.V_out', 'D1.V_in'])
        self.connect('R2.I', 'n2.I_in', tgt_indices=[0])
        self.connect('D1.I', 'n2.I_out', tgt_indices=[0])

        ...
```

So the main aspect is to connect output scalars to entries of an input vector similar to the `src_indices` option. Is there a way to do this or a reason against this?

Since we plan to use Dymos we`d like to use this functionality one dimension higher and connect output vectors to rows of input matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there is currently no `tgt_indices` like feature in OpenMDAO. Though it is technically feasible, it does present some API design and internal practical challenges. If you feel strongly about the need/value for this feature, you could consider submitting a [POEM](https://github.com/openmdao/poems) describing your proposed API for the dev-team to consider. You have a start on it with your provided example, but you'd need to think through details such as the following:

- what happens if a user gives both `src_indices` and `tgt_indices`?
- What do error msgs look like if there are overlapping `tgt_indices`
- How does the api extend to the `promotes` function.

In the meantime you'll either need to use a [MuxComponent](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.9.2/features/building_blocks/components/mux_demux_comps.html), or write your own version of that component that would take in array inputs and push them into the combined matrix. Its slightly inefficient to add a component like this, but in the grand scheme of things it should not be too bad (as long as you take the time to define analytic derivatives for it. It would be expensive to CS/FD this component).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The MuxComponent works for our issue and seems to be much shorter than adding a new component to combine arrays into a matrix. If the idea of target indices keeps coming up in our application we will think about a POEM. But considering the mentioned details and challenges it seems unlikely that the effort is worth it.